# Jquery Couchdb plugin Invalid Request URL

Tags: jquery, couchdb

earlier I asked a question about Couchdb and jQuery, later I found there was a plugin that could make the AJAX requests easier, but when I try to use it the URL that jQuery tries to connect with Couchdb is wrong(Request URL:file:///C:/_all_dbs - for the all_dbs function lets say). I am new to this and really couldn't find a solution anywhere. Thanks in advance! My javascript code is below.

```
$.couch.allDbs({
    success : function(dbs) {
        dbs.forEach(function(db) {
          console.log(db);
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you are running directly from a file system.Try a http server that serves your pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running CouchDB on the **5984** port and trying to access the data from a web page it will not work. A detailed explanation of this could be found here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1498-ask-ben-cross-site-ajax-requests-using-jquery-and-coldfusion.htm

I am also quite new to CouchDB, and if understood right, usually CouchApp is used to write "web apps". A detailed description of CouchApp could be found here:

https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted.md